# Can I sell to the public apps I made through Google App Maker

Tags: google-app-maker

From what I've read I can deploy apps to members of my organization or specific email addresses from google app maker. Am I able to sell these apps though through the google app store to the public?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a legal question, not a programming question.

Comment: It's a technical question, not a legal question.

Answer (score 3):

I received this answer to the same question previously:

"1) At this App Maker targets enterprise market and doesn't allow to create publicly available apps.
2) App Maker uses App Script as runtime and it has some quotas: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas "

Microsoft's PowerApps has the same restriction. Both of these are designed for distributing applications within your organisation only.

I am still looking for a low-code development environment similar to AppMaker that will allow me to build applications on Google Cloud Platform's App Engine and make them available to the public. Let me know if you find anything.